# How To Get Global MouseMove And KeyDown Events In Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, events, parent, childwindow, routed

Application.Current.RootVisual.KeyDown += Application_KeyDown

The above does not work if I'm on a ChildWindow - that was instantiated in runtime. My question is, how do I get the mousemove or keydown event in the Parent Window that hosts this ChildWindow?

Also, I'd rather not change anything in the childwindow (i.e., add an event that calls a parent's event directly). I'd just like to get a global keydown event. Is this is a possibility in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Global Keydown event.  You will need to assign the `Application_KeyDown` to the ChildWindow's `KeyDown` event when you call the `Show` method and remove it when the `Closed` event fires.

Comment: Is this still true for Silverlight 4 and 5?